# Which are non native file systems in the context of building firefox?

Tags: filesystems, compiling, firefox

Trying to build firefox and I have weird errors and kernel messages before a silent fail of the compilation process compiling over a `xfs` filesystem, but no fails while compiling over `jfs` in the same hardware (different partitions).

I read documentation about building firefox from source and I found this statement

```
Note: Building Firefox in Linux on top of a non-native file system - for example, on a mounted NTFS partition - is explicitly not supported. While a build environment like this may succeed it may also fail while claiming to have succeeded, which can be quite difficult to diagnose and fix.
```

So, Which ones are linux native file system ?

**Update**

When I built on `xfs` the file system becomes unusable, and for further details I will provide the exact kernel message

`[ 1514.286849] XFS: Assertion failed: (bip->bli_flags & XFS_BLI_STALE) || (xfs_blft_from_flags(&bip->__bli_format) > XFS_BLFT_UNKNOWN_BUF && xfs_blft_from_flags(&bip->__bli_format) < XFS_BLFT_MAX_BUF), file: fs/xfs/xfs_buf_item.c, line: 301
[ 1514.286876] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1514.286877] kernel BUG at fs/xfs/xfs_message.c:108!
[ 1514.286879] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[ 1514.286882] Modules linked in: w83627ehf hwmon_vid snd_seq_dummy snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss bnep rfcomm bluetooth rfkill snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek fuse nvidia(PO) uvcvideo videobuf2_core coretemp snd_hda_intel videodev snd_hda_codec rtc_cmos kvm_intel firewire_ohci firewire_core nv_tco videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops kvm snd_hwdep mousedev forcedeth evdev i2c_nforce2 snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc [last unloaded: i2c_dev]
[ 1514.286912] CPU: 0 PID: 14942 Comm: python Tainted: P           O 3.10.104-afterglow+ #8
[ 1514.286914] Hardware name:  EVGA  122-CK-NF68/122-CK-NF68, BIOS 6.00 PG 09/04/2008
[ 1514.286916] task: ffff880255def350 ti: ffff8801e465c000 task.ti: ffff8801e465c000
[ 1514.286917] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff812713fd>]  [<ffffffff812713fd>] assfail+0x1d/0x20
[ 1514.286925] RSP: 0018:ffff8801e465dba8  EFLAGS: 00010296
[ 1514.286927] RAX: 00000000000000e1 RBX: ffff880163671f90 RCX: ffff88025fc0d6b0
[ 1514.286929] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff88025fc0bf18 RDI: ffff88025fc0bf10
[ 1514.286931] RBP: ffff8801e465dba8 R08: 000000000000ffff R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1514.286932] R10: 0000000000000331 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8801604da118
[ 1514.286934] R13: 0000000000000002 R14: ffff880163671f60 R15: ffff8802346d6980
[ 1514.286936] FS:  00002b9103b34760(0000) GS:ffff88025fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1514.286938] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1514.286940] CR2: 00000000024ec1c8 CR3: 000000016279d000 CR4: 00000000000007f0
[ 1514.286942] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[ 1514.286943] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[ 1514.286944] Stack:
[ 1514.286946]  ffff8801e465dc38 ffffffff812d5777 0000000000000250 0000000000000050
[ 1514.286949]  ffff8801a50d1b00 0000000051eb851f ffff8801e465dc18 ffffffff8127861f
[ 1514.286952]  0000000000000001 0000000000000002 ffff8802347ac0e8 0000000000000002
[ 1514.286955] Call Trace:
[ 1514.286960]  [<ffffffff812d5777>] xfs_buf_item_format+0x97/0x400
[ 1514.286963]  [<ffffffff8127861f>] ? kmem_alloc+0x6f/0xe0
[ 1514.286966]  [<ffffffff812d4c48>] xfs_log_commit_cil+0xb8/0x550
[ 1514.286970]  [<ffffffff81042c11>] ? current_fs_time+0x11/0x50
[ 1514.286973]  [<ffffffff812cecad>] xfs_trans_commit+0xbd/0x290
[ 1514.286976]  [<ffffffff812cc917>] xfs_symlink+0x947/0x9c0
[ 1514.286980]  [<ffffffff8112f6fe>] ? __lookup_hash+0x1e/0x40
[ 1514.286983]  [<ffffffff8126ecad>] xfs_vn_symlink+0x4d/0xd0
[ 1514.286986]  [<ffffffff81133b0d>] vfs_symlink+0xcd/0x130
[ 1514.286989]  [<ffffffff81135cdd>] SyS_symlinkat+0x6d/0xd0
[ 1514.286992]  [<ffffffff81135d51>] SyS_symlink+0x11/0x20
[ 1514.286996]  [<ffffffff8165a4f2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 1514.286997] Code: 48 c7 c7 50 81 96 81 e8 32 aa dc ff c9 c3 55 48 89 f1 41 89 d0 48 89 e5 48 89 fa 48 c7 c6 38 53 95 81 31 ff 31 c0 e8 73 fc ff ff <0f> 0b 90 55 49 89 f9 48 89 e5 48 63 f6 48 83 ec 10 41 b8 01 00 
[ 1514.287026] RIP  [<ffffffff812713fd>] assfail+0x1d/0x20
[ 1514.287029]  RSP <ffff8801e465dba8>
[ 1514.287032] ---[ end trace b261b019fb030112 ]---`

Comment: `kernel BUG at fs/xfs/xfs_message.c:108!` - this doesn't look related to the Firefox build.

Comment: Exactly, can build the kernel itself and no problem appear, but if I try to build firefox this appears, I think that maybe xfs isn't native for firefox requirements and probably jfs is, but I dont understand

Comment: XFS would be a "native" file system. This is a kernel bug - as the code itself tells you. In general, it doesn't matter what you do in user space - if what you do crashes the kernel, it's a kernel bug. Exactly where the bug is really isn't as obvious as it seems.  The error logged might just be code that *discovers* the problem.  It might just be the code that stepped on the land mine, not the code that planted it.

Comment: I understand, it is just wierd that this doesnt happened in the jfs partition, but I was just confused about the non native file system in firefox build

Comment: LoL I really feel so silly now, thank you @Andew Henle and @Michael Homer. I become blind trying to justify the problem with the `non native file system` argument, I will try to make a bug report for the `xfs` but the question is still valid, which are the native file systems ?

Comment: It's not supported. Non-native would be for example a mounted NTFS partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement was added because of specific [build issue on NTFS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1148458), exact reason was not diagnosed but two candidates were "problem with the NTFS max path length" and "can't make symlinks on the NTFS partition", both are examples of difference in [filesystem semantics](http://www.conifersystems.com/2008/10/21/windows-vs-unix-file-system-semantics/) (Unix vs. Windows).

Comment: So probably, non-native is referring just to NTFS by this antecedent, or specifically some filesystem where there is not symbolic links support in the same ways or limits than *nix systems?

Comment: The latter.   NTFS is a good example, though.